# Scala: implicitly to implicit class

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Given:

```
implicit class Foo(val i: Int) {
   def addValue(v: Int): Int = i + v
}
```

is it possible apply to it any `implicitly`?
I get an error here:

```
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Foo
       implicitly[Foo]
```

Comment: `implicitly[Foo](4)` will return `res0: Foo = Foo@5d5eef3d`.

Comment: That's because of the same reason that `val foo: Foo = 4` compiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `implicit class Foo(val i: Int)` means that there is an *implicit conversion* from `Int` to `Foo`. So `implicitly[Int => Foo]` should work.

Think about it like this: if you could summon a `Foo` with `implicitly[Foo]`, which `Foo` would you expect to get? A `Foo(0)`? A `Foo(1)`? A `Foo(2)`?

Answer (score 1):

For further details,

`implcitly` key word can be explained as following

> implitly[T] means **return implicit value of type T in the context**

Which means, to get `Foo` implicitly you need to create an implicit value in the scope

For example,

```
 implicit class Foo(val i: Int) {
   def addValue(v: Int): Int = i + v
 } 

 implicit val foo:Foo = Foo(1)
 val fooImplicitly = implicitly[Foo] // Foo(1)
```

Also, note that `Foo` itself is only a class,

But by putting implicit key word in front of class definition,

Compiler creates an implicit function of type `Int => Foo`